# Are there sites that support editing and ordering photo prints, cards, and books on an iPad?

Tags: ipad, printing, mobileme, photos, image-editing

I'm reposting this question (unchanged) from [webapps.stackexchange.com](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/5745/), because I've received no answers there and this seems like an appropriate question for the Apple Stack Exchange site.

---

I've tried the Shutterfly iPad app, which allows uploading photos, but doesn't support any other functionality available on the website. And I can't edit photos or design cards and books from the Mobile Safari browswer on the iPad, presumably because those features use Flash.

Are there any other photo websites that provide either a full-featured iPad app (that includes creating cards and books and ordering prints) or an iPad or iPhone app that allows uploading photos and a website that allows one to create cards and books and order prints in Mobile Safari?

Note, I download photos directly from my camera to the iPad, so I'm trying to figure out how to avoid any need for a PC.

Someone (on [vark.com](http://vark.com/t/SZwNAG)) recommended Apple's MobileMe (http://me.com).  But http://www.apple.com/mobileme/features/gallery.html doesn't show that it supports editing photos and ordering prints, cards, and books.  Does anyone have experience with MobileMe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't really have a direct answer for you, but I would like to help by sharing what I know.

I have a Mobile Me account, and there are no tools for editing your photos online. It's an image gallery. A gallery is meant just for viewing and not for editing.

Mobile Me was designed to work in conjunction with the iLife software on a desktop mac. You edit the photos, order the prints, make the cards, and the books in the iPhoto app on the Mac.

Photo editing on the iPad is the easy part, but I think you are approaching it from the wrong angle. There are tons of free (and cheap) apps that allow you to edit photos. (Photoshop Mobile for instance. Just check the Photography category in the App Store). Once you edit them in an app, then I would upload them to a service that supports printing services. The hard part is going to be the ordering of prints, cards and books from the iPad.

We can only hope that sometime in the near future, Apple creates a mobile version of iPhoto just as they did with iMovie. That would be ideal.

**EDIT**

1. You can order prints from this app as well:
   http://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=323705153&mt=8%3FpartnerId%3D30&siteID=KEmRFwU0WKY-yY5rDqaKJMaSUWCfbLPC3w
2. You can also order prints from the Walgreens app:
   http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/walgreens/id335364882?mt=8
3. This might solve your issue as well!
   http://www.ritzpix.com/net/OrderPrints/
4. You might want to check out this app and service:
   http://www.ecce-terram.com/order-solutions/mobile-client.html

> ECCE TERRAM announced a new service this week that will allow people to order prints of photos stored on their iPhones from the phones themselves. With their **Photo2lab Client**, users may select a photo (both those taken with the iPhone and those transfered from iPhoto), add text and create prints, post cards and even mini photo books. You'll even be able to add an address to a post card from the iPhone's built-in contacts list.

Comment: Wow! I love to know more of those sites that support editing and ordering photo print cards and books.

Answer (score 2):

I downloaded the Walgreens app and emailed pics to my local store.  The only problem is if you edit your photos on the iPad, it doesn't transfer to the store.  So just use their browse and edit button, fix the pics there and create an album, send and pick up in hours.  So far this has worked.

Answer (score 0):

Only answer I can think of would be something like Phanfare loading up to flikr/Phanfare or via SmugMug and the smugshot app combined with the smugmug webpage (which is not mobile friendly, but isn't flash infested either).

Comment: I hadn't heard of Phanfare.  How is it different from Flickr or SmugMug?  Does it (or SmugMug) allow editing photos on an iPad?  Flickr uses Picnik for editing photos, which uses Flash (so it won't work on an iPad).

Answer (score -2):

Just released.  I hope this helps:

http://itunes.apple.com/app/roes/id533327862?mt=8